# Django cannot find new modules, using pyenv and virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, pyenv

I’m sure this is pretty straightforward to someone experienced. I’m learning Django through the Wedge of Django ebook.

I’m using Python 3.8.7 installed via pyenv like so:
`pyenv install 3.8.7`

Then I’ve set up a virtualenv like so:
`pyenv virtualenv 3.8.7 everycheese`

I activate the virtualenv in my repo like so:
`pyenv local everycheese`

The environment is shown as active in the prompt, as it starts with (everycheese).

The main project is cloned from Django Cookiecutter
https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django

I’ve then used pip to install requirements from the requirements.txt files.

However - I’m running into trouble when I try to add new packages (by adding the package to requirements.txt as a new line and installing again with pip).

`pip list`, or `pip freeze` both show the new module. But when I add the module to my INSTALLED_APPS and try to import it in my models.py file, Django cannot find it.

When I type
`which python`, and `which pip`, they point to different directories and I think this may be part of the problem but I am stuck.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense and really appreciate you sharing. I ran `python - m pip list` and the modules were not there. `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` then worked like a charm. Thank you! If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as resolved. Cheers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `pip` (or actually any other Python script), it is important to make sure which Python interpreter is used. Usually it is obvious which Python interpreter is used when calling `pip`. But sometimes it is not clear, and the script is actually running with a different interpreter that one might think. Which leads to unexpected results and a lot of confusion.

Therefore it is always better to call explicitly the exact Python interpreter you are targeting and tell it to run *pip*'s ***executable module*** (or any other executable module). Typically:

```
$ python -m pip install Something
$ # instead of 'pip install Something'
$ python3 -m pip install Something
$ # instead of 'pip3 install Something'
```

If there is still doubt, one could even go one step further and use a more explicit path to the Python interpreter explicitly:

- `/the/path/to/my/pythonX.Y -m pip`
- `path/to/my/pythonX.Y -m pip`
- `path/to/my/python -m pip`
- `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip`
- `pythonX.Y -m pip`
- `python3 -m pip`
- `python -m pip`

***Resource***:

- [Brett Cannon's article "Why you should use `python -m pip`"](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/)

Comment: Thanks again! Great article!
It helped me understand the root cause of the problem.

Comment: For anyone else that runs into this issue - I had previously installed python without pyenv using the macOS version, and this had added lines to my .bash_profile which meant calling `pip` without `python -m pip` used a system pip instead of the pyenv pip. 

By removing the PATH modification from my `.bash_profile`, it removed any errors caused when running coverage later on.